# Desktop application - Identity Server 4 - HTTP 400 status error

Tags: identityserver4, windows-forms-core

I have a Windows desktop client which connects to Identity server using Authorization code + PKCE.
It seems to work perfectly fine if I run it through visual studio.
I have then installed the desktop client on my own machine and it connects to Identity Server, displays the log in screen and then logs in fine.

For some reason though, when I install that same desktop client on a server, or even the same server that it sits on, then it displays the login screen but when I enter credentials and click on login, then it displays the following HTTP 400 error....
This error (HTTP 400 Bad Request) means that this program was able to connect to the web server, but the webpage could not be found because of a problem with the address.

I don't understand what could be going wrong or what could be different between the desktop client sat on my machine or the one sat on a server.

I would appreciate whatever help I could get on this.

The main thing I can see is that it doesn't even seem to hit my Identity Server 4 LogIn post controller method (but does hit the Get method as expected).
Note - I am using an In Browser control on Windows so it is Identity Server that seems to be the post and erroring out with the HTTP 400 error.

Comment: HTTPS/Certificate problem?

Comment: Installed the same certificate both locally and on the server

Comment: What errors if any do you get in the browser console? and what is the full URL that fails?

Comment: I can see an error message which says "Missing authorization code"

Comment: For what URL request? You could perhaps have some CORS or Cookie SameSite attribute issue.

Comment: Are you using the .Net server-side client to connect to IdentityServer? IdentityModel assembly? Or a basic HttpClient class? Your response_mode in IDS4 should be form_post for POST

Answer (score 0):

We fixed it by implementing ValidateIssuerName = true (previously was false) and everything else that was needed with that.
Previously, ID4 on discovery mode was giving its own URL, whereas we updated it to provide the URL of the gateway.